# How to make a proess run in the Background in Windows?

Tags: background

How can i run a process like a Visual Studio,Eclips,Selenium type of process in the Background in Windows ??? I want to run these kind of process from a batch file.
Please help.

Thank You,

Comment: Adding a little more info might help.  Which process do you want in the background, and why?  It may be that a completely different tool or process would solve your problem better.  (It sounds like you may be looking for `makefile` or `msbuild` or something similar, but it's hard to tell).

Comment: @Dan Pichelman: I want to launch an 'Eclips Project' using .bat file and I want the eclips to open in the background.It should not be visible to the user,when they run the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use task scheduler in Winodws